# Combinatorics concerning circular arrangement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A group of 18 Scandinavians consists of $5$ Norwegians, $6$ Swedes, and $7$ Finns. They are seated at random around a table. Compute the following probabilities:

(a) that all the Norwegians sit together,

(b) that all the Norwegians and all the Swedes sit together, and

(c) that all the Norwegians, all the Swedes, and all the Finns sit together.

For (b) I don't understand why this is different from (c)?

If all Norwegians and all the Swedes sit together then wouldn't that mean that whatever seats left are going to be filled by the Fins?

therefore shouldn't the answer be $\frac {2!7!5!6!}{17!}$

I don't understand why the answer given for part be is $\frac {8!6!5!}{17!}$

Comment: The situation in (b) is different from (c) since there are two disconnected regions the Finns could be sitting at: for example "Finn Finn Norwegian Norwegian Finn Swede Swede" would be valid in (b) but not in (c).

Comment: the wording is very confusing, I thought they meant sitting together as in no gaps between the two groups.  with that said I  still I don't get why the answer for b is $\frac {8!6!5!}{17!}$ where did the 8! come from?

Comment: $8=7+1+1-1$: 7 Finns, 1 group of Swedes, 1 group of Norwegians and -1 since we have a circular arrangement, which is why we have $17!$ instead of $18!$ in the denominator as well.

Comment: @Christoph thanks for the explanation I have to wrap my head around it little more

Comment: In a circular arrangement, only the relative order of the people matters.  Seat a particular Finn.  Call him Harri.  Relative to Harri, there are eight objects to arrange as we proceed clockwise around the table, the block of five Norwegians, the block of six Swedes, and the other six Finns.